# Create element "datalist"?

Tags: javascript, html

How to create datalist dynamically?

Was able to dynamically create a drop down using create element and append child but am struggling with datalist.

```
 <script>
  let counter = 0;
  function myFunction3() {
    if (counter < 5) {
      counter++;
      /*var text = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
      text.id = "text" + counter;
      document.body.appendChild(text);*/
      var drdwn = document.createElement("datalist");
      drdwn.id = "drdwn" + counter;
      document.body.appendChild(drdwn);
      var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
      opt1.text = "<";
      opt1.value = "<";
      document.getElementById("drdwn" + counter).appendChild(opt1);
      var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
      opt2.text = ">";
      opt2.value = ">";
      document.getElementById("drdwn" + counter).appendChild(opt2);
      var opt3 = document.createElement("option");
      opt3.text = "=";
      opt3.value = "=";
      document.getElementById("drdwn" + counter).appendChild(opt3);
      /*var value = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
      value.id = "value" + counter;
      document.body.appendChild(value);*/
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: A `<datalist>` needs a corresponding `<input>`. Check out [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Comment: To follow up on that, you can link a `<datalist>` to an `<input>` by setting the input's `list` attribute to the `id` of the datalist you want to use. The documentation for the `<datalist>` element can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const options = document.querySelector('.options');
  const datalistCreator = document.querySelector('.datalist-creator');
  const datalistsBlock = document.querySelector('.datalists');
  let counter = 0;

  datalistCreator.addEventListener('click', function() {
   const datalist = document.createElement('datalist');
   const output = document.createElement('input');

   datalist.setAttribute('id', 'datalist' + counter);
   output.setAttribute('list', 'datalist' + counter);
   output.placeholder = 'Datalist of ' + options.value;
   
   for (let i = 0; i < options.value; i++) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i + 1;
    datalist.appendChild(option)
   }

   datalistsBlock.appendChild(datalist);
   datalistsBlock.appendChild(output);
   counter++;

   return output;
  })
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options">
<button class="datalist-creator">Create datalist</button>
<div class="datalists"></div>
```